# Lotus Error - you must provide an item name

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

```
 Sub Click(Source As Button)
   Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
   Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
   Dim doc As NotesDocument
   Dim item As NotesItem
   Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
   Set doc = uidoc.Document
   Set item = doc.GetFirstItem(“FieldName”)
   Call item.AppendToTextList("TextIWantToAppend")
End Sub
```

When debugging, I get the error on getfirstitem, but I don't know why because it is the correct name of the text field (allowed multiple values)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the correct quotation mark: `"`.

So change to this:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
   Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
   Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
   Dim doc As NotesDocument
   Dim item As NotesItem
   Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
   Set doc = uidoc.Document
   Set item = doc.GetFirstItem("FieldName")
   Call item.AppendToTextList("TextIWantToAppend")
End Sub
```

Comment: Now there is no error, but nothing is added to the field either.

Comment: Is your document in *edit* mode? Has AppendToTextList's parameter the "good" quotation marks?

Comment: I added these  lines:
Call workspace.EditDocument( True )
...
Call doc.Save(True,False)
Call uidoc.Save

It works, the text is appended but when I close the form and reopen it, the field is empty and I start again.

Comment: Is the field a computed field with a value formula?

Comment: So, the field is filled - after saving document and as long as document is open. Reasons, why field is empty after closing and reopening document, can be: (1) You have a field "SaveOptions" with value "0" in form, (2) you have code in form events or fields that delete or empty this certain field. Just search in Designer at menu "Search / File..." in current project for this "FieldName".

Comment: Or it might be a Computed for Display field, whose value isn't saved.

Answer (score 1):

Hi are you sure that the field isnt a RichtTextItem?
maybe it helps

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
   Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
   Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
   Dim doc As NotesDocument
   Dim item As NotesRichTextItem
   Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
   Set doc = uidoc.Document
   Set item = doc.GetFirstItem("FieldName")
   Call item.AppendToTextList("TextIWantToAppend")
End Sub
```

And make sure that the NotesUIDocument is saved, before you try to open the Item.